# c++ windows api: disabled menu grayed?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm testing the windows API's menu states (disabled, grayed, checked...) but there's something I don't understand. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-appendmenuw) states that `MF_DISABLED` does not gray an item but here's what I get:

[image]

with this code:

```
HMENU menuBar = CreateMenu();
HMENU hopMenu = CreateMenu();

AppendMenuW(menuBar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hopMenu, L"hop");
AppendMenuW(hopMenu, MF_STRING, 0, L"Enabled");

AppendMenuW(hopMenu, MF_STRING | MF_DISABLED, 1, L"Disabled");
AppendMenuW(hopMenu, MF_STRING | MF_GRAYED, 2, L"Grayed");
AppendMenuW(hopMenu, MF_STRING | MF_CHECKED, 3, L"Checked");

AppendMenuW(hopMenu, MF_STRING | MF_DISABLED | MF_CHECKED, 4, L"Disabled && Checked");
AppendMenuW(hopMenu, MF_STRING | MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED, 5, L"Disabled && Grayed");

AppendMenuW(hopMenu, MF_STRING | MF_CHECKED | MF_GRAYED, 6, L"Checked && Grayed");

SetMenu(hwnd, menuBar);
```

How can I have a disabled menu item not grayed, then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These two are now the same. See [tagMENUITEMINFOA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagmenuiteminfoa) for more info.

Both `MFS_DISABLED` and `MFS_GRAYED` are grayed now as they represent the same value of `0x00000003L`

Comment: Actually `MFS_DISABLED` is exactly the same value as `MFS_GRAYED`.

Comment: Actually the OP was mentioning `MF_GRAYED` and `MF_DISABLED` wich have  not the same value, rather than of `MFS_GRAYED` and `MFS_DISABLED` which _have_ the same value, so my comment is somewhat misleading.